# Trigger a cloud task at a specific region

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

In Firebase, While enqueuing the tasks, how can I specify the region of the cloud task that I want to be triggered?

I am using Cloud Tasks in firebase to handle background processing. My Default GCP resource location
is "us-central" and the cloud task is in "europe-west1". When I try to trigger the function, it tries to find the cloud task in "us-central". How can I make it point to "europe-west1"?

```
exports.tasks = functions
    .region("us-central1")
    .tasks.taskQueue({
        retryConfig: {
            maxAttempts: 5,
            minBackoffSeconds: 60,
        },
        rateLimits: {
            maxConcurrentDispatches: 6,
        },
    }).onDispatch(async (data) => {
        const { handletasks } = require("./modules/taskHandler");

        return await handletasks(data);
    });
```

```
const { getFunctions } = require('firebase-admin/functions');

const enqueueTasks = async (type, data) => {

    const queue = getFunctions().taskQueue("tasks");

    const enqueues = [];

    const scheduleDelaySeconds = 60;

    enqueues.push(
        queue.enqueue({
            type,
            data
        },
            {
                scheduleDelaySeconds,
                dispatchDeadlineSeconds: 60 * 5 // 5 minutes
            },
        ),
    );

    await Promise.all(enqueues);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, then I noticed `taskQueue()` has this description in my IDE:

> Creates a reference to a TaskQueue for a given function name. The
> function name can be either:
>
> A fully qualified function resource name:
> `projects/{project}/locations/{location}/functions/{functionName}`
>
> A partial resource name with location and function name, in which case
> the runtime project ID is used:
> `locations/{location}/functions/{functionName}`
>
> A partial function name, in which case the runtime project ID and the
> default location, `us-central1`, is used: `{functionName}`
>
> @param `functionName` — The name of the function.
>
> @param `extensionId` — Optional Firebase extension ID.
>
> @returns — A promise that fulfills with a TaskQueue.

So the trick was to make `queue` like this:

```TypeScript
  const queue = getFunctions().taskQueue(
    `locations/${location}/functions/${functionName}`
  );
```